# ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOVLED on select websites

Tags: networking, dns

Since yesterday I've often been unable to open websites like Google, Github and Spotify, but most other websites seem to work fine.

I've flushed the dns cache many times already, used different DNS servers and rebooted my pc, however this same issue also occurs on all of my other devices.

Restarting my router seems to help for a few hours but then the same issue comes up again.
The websites are SOMETIMES reachable through ping and tracert, but only rarely.

I am not using any proxy or vpn.

Comment: Theoretically, there may be a possible (temporary) issue with your ISP or another routing issue outside your local network.

Comment: that the router reboot has any impact indicates your router is likely caching dns responses, and is failing to invalidate that cache appropriately. clearing the local cache does nothing if there is a bad cache upstream, though that should only really work if your router is set as your DNS server. ping and tracert won't be much use to you for troubleshooting this, but NSLookup probably will.  also note that DNS queries are readable on the wire, so upstream nodes might edit your queries or responses (like blackholing servers).